# AWS Cognito: should you make a custom attribute for a UID?

Tags: amazon-cognito

I want a unique ID for my users in my cognito user pool that can be used in databases. The `sub` attribute I don't think I want to use because if I ever migrate the data, those will be changed. Is it common practice to generate your own UID for users and set it as a custom attribute to your users when they are created? Is there a better way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common practice is using **sub** as ListUser supports filtering by sub. Best way would be using both username and sub. This way, if you ever decide to migrate your userpool, you easily lookup your database and replace the sub value with new one.